# String appending of Regex in SQL (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql, regex, string, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to use the REPLACE function in SQL and I am having problems with trying to append a string to the end of the current contents of a column.

```
set ActualRegex = REPLACE(ActualRegex, ActualRegex, ActualRegex + '[\d\D]*')
```

These strings will be used for Regex checks in a C# program, but that's not particularly relevant to the problem.

When I try running this query, i end up getting an error message

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I've checked the field sizes, and the resulting strings will not be nearly long enough to exceed the size of the field (varchar(512)).  At biggest they might be 50 characters long unless something strange is happening that I'm unaware about.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** Here's the full query

```
update [Registration].[dbo].[MigrationOfTagTypes] set ActualRegex = 
REPLACE(ActualRegex, ActualRegex, ActualRegex + '[\d\D]*') 
where Regex != '' and Regex like '%\%' escape '\'
```

**EDIT:** Actually, I figured it out and turns out I was just being stupid and overlooking something small.  Apparently these fields were filled with lots of empty whitespace appended onto the end of the strings, so appending to that would result in breaking the size constraint.  **Thanks for all the help!**

Comment: Is this part of an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Yes, the entire statement is:  update [Registration].[dbo].[MigrationOfTagTypes]
set ActualRegex = REPLACE(ActualRegex, ActualRegex, ActualRegex + '[\d\D]*') 
     where Regex != '' and Regex like '%\%' escape '\'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

There are two reasons for this:

1. Your varchar column is not large enough. Appending 7 characters to an existing 10 into a varchar(15) column won't work
2. Your column is defined as char (why?!). Char columns have implicit trailing spaces, so if you add 'ABC' to a char(10) field containing 'XYZ', it actually ends up as 'XYZ       ABC' (13) which is longer than char(10).

In the 2nd case, i.e. char columns, use RTRIM

```
update [Registration].[dbo].[MigrationOfTagTypes] set ActualRegex = 
RTRIM(REPLACE(ActualRegex, ActualRegex, ActualRegex + '[\d\D]*')) 
where Regex != '' and Regex like '%\%' escape '\'
```

Note: using replace like this allows `'ABCxxxABC'` to become `'ABC[\d\D]*xxxABC[\d\D]*'`

If you simply wanted to `append to the end of the column`, then you would use

```
update [Registration].[dbo].[MigrationOfTagTypes]
set ActualRegex = RTRIM(ActualRegex) + '[\d\D]*'
where Regex != '' and Regex like '%\%' escape '\'
```

Comment: " At biggest they might be 50 characters long unless something strange is happening that I'm unaware about."  I think you're still correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that [concat](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html) is more useful?

As far as the error message goes, I do not know why it is generated, but than again, it has been a while since I used MS SQL for the last time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's possible that your column is being aggregated recursively, ad infinitum.  Or at least ad 512 characters.

If this is the case, you'll have to offload the current table contents into a temporary table, then use that data to perform the update back onto the original table.

I'm researching if this is possible right now.

Comment: That sounds rather interesting.  Oddly enough it sounds like the most likely problem happening.

Comment: Can you change the column to a VARCHAR(MAX) and try it?  Otherwise, try the temp table idea.